# Reading nested dynamic JSON attributes

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, nested

First of all I have checked all old questions and found this one useful: [Reading dynamic attributes of json into .net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676295/reading-dynamic-attributes-of-json-into-net-c-sharp) but wasn't so useful in my case, I'm missing something not sure what is it!

I'm trying to read dynamic JSON with nested dynamic attributes, here is the JSON:

```
{"data":{"cart":{"seats":{"3B00535EF2414332":{"212":{"6":["22","21"]}}}}}}
```

Please keep in mind that `3B00535EF2414332`, `212` and `6` are dynamic each time I get this JSON.
In C#, I don't know how should I set the attributes as I need to provide a class with properties with exact the same name of the object to deserialize this object. I though about parsing it to dynamic object in C# and try to call it, but still can't as the only known value for me each time is `3B00535EF2414332` but other 2 dynamic properties are not known to me, I need to retrieve them.

I though about the dictionary way, but I couldn't create it right. Actually, I didn't understand it right.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what values are you trying to extract here? (22 and 21)?

Comment: Nope, I need to get 3B00535EF2414332 , 212, 6, 22, 21, gonna test your solution, thanks.

Comment: are they always in this structure (int[] under 3 layers from `data.cart.seats`)?

Comment: Yes, they are always like that static, but after that went dynamic..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var results = JObject.Parse(json)
    ["data"]["cart"]["seats"]
    .Children<JProperty>().First().Value
    .Children<JProperty>().First().Value
    .Children<JProperty>().First().Value
    .ToObject<int[]>();
```

EDIT: you can also use this to retrieve the values along with the path names:

```
var seats = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["cart"]["seats"].Children<JProperty>();
var unknown0 = seats.First();
var unknown1 = unknown0.Value.Children<JProperty>().First();
var unknown2 = unknown1.Value.Children<JProperty>().First();

// unknown0.Name -> 3B00535EF2414332
// unknown1.Name -> 212
// unknown2.Name -> 6;
// unknown2.Value.ToObject<int[]>() -> [22,21]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if there aren't any children, after the first `.Children...`?

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot. Got all data I want with this!

Comment: @MeghanArmes, I think it gonna return Null or even throw exception, that's why you may use FirstOrDefault, so you can handle if it's with null!

Comment: @AhmedÕşşama that makes sense. :) Good call!

Comment: @MeghanArmes For the record, you will get a `InvalidOperationException` "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: @Xiaoy312 that makes sense -- no Children, no elements in the sequence. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @Xiaoy312, Thanks for this edit also, Don't worry I figured that out before you say and you confirm it as well! Thanks a lot! ;)